# How to add root element to array in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to deserialize class to XML documnet. I have:

```
public partial class CurveType : AbstractCurveType {

    private AbstractCurveSegmentType[] segmentsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [ XmlElement(Type = typeof(ArcType)),
      XmlElement(Type = typeof(CircleType)),
      XmlElement(Type = typeof(LineStringSegmentType), ElementName = "LineStringSegment")]
    public AbstractCurveSegmentType[] segments {
        get {
            return this.segmentsField;
        }
        set {
            this.segmentsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So `segments` can contains objects of types `ArcType`, `CircleType` or `LineStringSegmentType`.

Now it deserializing in:

```
 <gml:Curve>
   <gml:LineStringSegment>
    ***
   </gml:LineStringSegment>
 </gml:Curve>
```

But i want to see:

```
  <gml:Curve>
   <gml:segments>
      <gml:LineStringSegment>
        ***
      </gml:LineStringSegment>
   </gml:segments>
 </gml:Curve>
```

When i remove annotation `XmlElement` i got my `<gml:segments>` but in this case all `<gml:LineStringSegment>` turn into `<gml:AbstractCurveSegmentType type='LineStringSegment'>`.

How can i add this `<gml:segments>` root element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and create another class which will act like a wrapper:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Curve")]
public class ObjectModel {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "segments")]
    public CurveType CurveTypes {get; set;}
}
```

Then initialize the objects and serialize them:

```
AbstractCurveSegmentType[] arr = new AbstractCurveSegmentType[] 
{
    new ArcType { Id = 1, ArcTypeName = "arcTypeName"},
    new CircleType { Id = 2, CircleTypeName = "circleTypeName"}
};


var obj = new ObjectModel
{
    CurveTypes = new CurveType { segments = arr }
};

var xml = Xml.Serialize(obj);
```

This is the helper method for serialization:

```
public class Xml
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

And you get the following xml:

```xml
<Curve>
  <segments>
    <ArcType>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <ArcTypeName>arcTypeName</ArcTypeName>
    </ArcType>
    <CircleType>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <CircleTypeName>circleTypeName</CircleTypeName>
    </CircleType>
  </segments>
</Curve>
```